# Unity World Space Shader Gradient Color

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm doing a unity project to get depth data from Microsoft Kinect and build a terrain in Unity with those data. And I use world space shader to color the terrain with gradient color. My current problem is the gradient can only be seen when zoom in in Scene view. When zoom out, all the colors disappear. See the below screenshots. I'm struggling with it for long time. Anybody knows what the problem is? Thank you.

[image: Zoom out effect]
[image: Zoom in effect]

```
Shader "Custom/Terrain World Space Shader" {

   Properties{
  _Color("Basic Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) // White colorr
  _Height0("Max Height for Texture 0", float) = 2.0
  _Textre0("Texture 0 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height1("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 4.0
  _Textre1("Texture 1 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height2("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 6.0
  _Texture2("Texture 2 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height3("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 8.0
  _Texture3("Texture 3 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height4("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 10.0
  _Texture4("Texture 4 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height5("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 12.0
  _Texture5("Texture 5 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height6("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 14.0
  _Texture6("Texture 6 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height7("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 16.0
  _Texture7("Texture 7 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height8("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 18.0
  _Texture8("Texture 8 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height9("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 20.0
  _Texture9("Texture 9 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height10("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 22.0
  _Texture10("Texture 10 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height11("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 24.0
  _Texture11("Texture 11 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Height12("Max Height for Texture 1", float) = 26.0
  _Texture12("Texture 12 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Texture13("Texture 13 (RGB)", 2D) = "surface" {}
  _Scale("Texture Scale", Float) = 1.0
   }

  SubShader{
  Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma surface surf Lambert

  struct Input {
  float3 worldNormal;
  float3 worldPos; 
  };

  sampler2D _Texture0;
  sampler2D _Texture1;
  sampler2D _Texture2;
  sampler2D _Texture3;
  sampler2D _Texture4;
  sampler2D _Texture5;
  sampler2D _Texture6;
  sampler2D _Texture7;
  sampler2D _Texture8;
  sampler2D _Texture9;
  sampler2D _Texture10;
  sampler2D _Texture11;
  sampler2D _Texture12;
  sampler2D _Texture13;
  float _Height0;
  float _Height1;
  float _Height2;
  float _Height3;
  float _Height4;
  float _Height5;
  float _Height6;
  float _Height7;
  float _Height8;
  float _Height9;
  float _Height10;
  float _Height11;
  float _Height12;
  float4 _Color;
  float _Scale;

  void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
     float2 UV;
     fixed4 c;
     UV = IN.worldPos.xz;
     if (IN.worldPos.y < _Height0) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture0, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height0 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height1) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture1, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height1 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height2) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture2, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height2 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height3) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture3, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height3 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height4) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture4, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height4 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height5) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture5, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height5 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height6) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture6, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height6 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height7) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture7, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height7 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height8) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture8, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height8 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height9) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture9, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height9 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height10) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture10, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height10 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height11) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture11, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height11 && IN.worldPos.y < _Height12) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture12, UV* _Scale);
     }
     else if (IN.worldPos.y >= _Height12) {
        c = tex2D(_Texture13, UV* _Scale);
     }
     o.Albedo = c.rgb * _Color;
  }

  ENDCG
}

 Fallback "VertexLit"
}
```

Comment: Since it seems like the shader is being applied, the most likely culprit is the shader itself. Perhaps it is using camera space rather than world space? If you post a [reproducible example](http://sscce.org/) that would help.

Comment: @rutter Thanks for your answer. I attached my shader code, can you point out the difference? Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. It's 'Base Map Dist' settings.

Answer (score 2):

Set terrain 'Base Map Dist' settings with a larger number, and all gradient colors will show up.